# How to add many functions in ONE ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've be looking for how to execute this but I can't find anything related so far, :( 
I could nest both functions yes but I'm just wondering if this is possible?
I'd like to do this literally:

```
<td><button class="btn" ng-click="edit($index) open()">Open me!</button></td>
```

My JS code at the moment:

```
$scope.open = function () {
  $scope.shouldBeOpen = true;
};      

$scope.edit = function(index){

  var content_1, content_2;
      content_1 = $scope.people[index].name;
      content_2 = $scope.people[index].age;

  console.log(content_1);
};
```

I'd like to call two functions with just one click, how can I do this in angularJS?
I thought it'd be straight forward like in CSS when you add multiple classes...but it's not :(

Answer (score 726, accepted):

You have 2 options :

1. Create a third method that wrap both methods. Advantage here is that you put less logic in your template.
2. Otherwise if you want to add 2 calls in ng-click you can add ';' after `edit($index)` like this

   `ng-click="edit($index); open()"`

See here : http://jsfiddle.net/laguiz/ehTy6/

Comment: I've used method two (which does what's needed), but what reasons are there *not* to have two calls in one `ng-click`?

Comment: Both work it's just a matter of trying to put the logic in your controllers only. In that case not a big deal :)

Comment: I see absolutely nothing wrong with option 2 as it is a directive's (such as ng-click's) job to map user action to scope behavior.

Comment: That's why I gave 2 options. Personally I prefer to wrap calls in my controller but it's up to you.

Comment: Is there any harm in using Option 2 ?

Comment: There's no problem with option 2 but option 1 is cleaner since you should avoid adding code and logic in your views. It's better if you need to modify something in the future.

Comment: Option 2 has one minor issue: angular needs a bit longer to parse the expression I guess (as it discovers the ";" between the two functions and then has to parse the two parts separately). However I found one good reason when to use option 2: If you HAVE to call the first function on the current scope of that specific element in the DOM tree and the other function in a different context (i.e. controller)

Comment: In my own case, Option 2 means avoiding adding a common function inside a directive, which is probably slower and definitely harder to maintain.

Comment: Option 1 also gives you one more unnecessary function to have to test

Comment: How to do that in angular 2+ ? (action1 ; action2 not working)

Comment: @Emeric I just tested it in Angular 15 and it works without problems.

Answer (score 28):

You can call multiple functions with ';'

```
ng-click="edit($index); open()"
```

Answer (score 18):

A lot of people use (click) option so I will share this too.

```
<button (click)="function1()" (click)="function2()">Button</button>
```

Comment: Using (click)="function(); function2()" works as well. I just found that out and wanted to share.

Comment: I found this useful when binding to `keyup.enter`. The `;` separation didn't work because the methods were not always executing in order.

Answer (score 12):

The standard way to add Multiple functions

```
<button (click)="removeAt(element.bookId); openDeleteDialog()"> Click Here</button>
```

or

```
<button (click)="removeAt(element.bookId)" (click)="openDeleteDialog()"> Click Here</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

- Make a collection of functions
- Make a function that loops through and executes all the functions in the collection.
- Add the function to the html

```
array = [
    function() {},
    function() {},
    function() {}
]

function loop() {
    array.forEach(item) {
        item()
    }
}

ng - click = "loop()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below

```
ng-click="anyFunction()"

anyFunction() {
   // call another function here
   anotherFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" (click)="open(content)" style="position: fixed;  bottom: 0;  right: 130px;"
                    class="btn col-sm-1  btn-Danger" >
                    Reject
                </button>
                  
                  

                <ng-template #content let-modal>
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
                      <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                     
                        <div class="mb-3">
                          <label class="bg-danger text-light" for="Reject">Reason For reject</label>
                          
                            <textarea   matInput placeholder="  Reject" [(ngModel)]="asset_note">{{note}}</textarea>
                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <!-- -->
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="reject();modal.close('Save click') ">Save</button>
                    </div>
                  </ng-template> 


**.ts file**
open(content: any) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }


close()
{

this.getDismissReason(ModalDismissReasons.ESC);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which of the following is best practice (option1 or option2)

1. <button (click)="removeAt(element.bookId); openDeleteDialog()"> Click Here
2. <button (click)="removeAt(element.bookId)" (click)="openDeleteDialog()"> Click Here

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33269814)

Answer (score -15):

```
ng-click "$watch(edit($index), open())"
```

Comment: Syntax here is incorrect. As explained above, the semicolon is the delimiter; not a comma... Among other things...