# Using ng-click to call two different functions

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way I can get `ng-click` to call two functions?

I would like something along the lines of

```
ng-click ="{search(),match()}"
```

Instead of how I have it now, which is:

```
ng-click = "search()"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add many functions in ONE ng-click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813945/how-to-add-many-functions-in-one-ng-click)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can call multiple functions with ';'

```
ng-click="search(); match()"
```

Comment: are you sure? That doesn't seem to work for me

EDIT: Nvm, its actually ng-click="search();match()"

Thanks for leading me to the right answer!

Comment: You can do it, however this is not best practice. e.g if you are passing events through, something can kill the second function so it will never execute. This way is possible but not best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Please use search() one function and add a callback function of match() inside search() function;

```
ng-click = "search()";
```

Answer (score 0):

using the ng-click to call function:

```
ng-click="search()"
```

using the callback approach if function search () depends on the value returned by function math ()
in the controller do:

```
$scope.match() = function(cb){

//do something and return value
        var x = 10;
        x = x+10;

cb(x)

};

$scope.search() = function(){

   //call math function 
   $scope.match(function(value){

   myCalc = value;

   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  multiple methods with `(click)` separated by `;`

```
(click)="search();match()"
```