# Multiple Expression in Angular Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm putting two expressions in an Angular ngClick directive. Why would $scope.refresh not = Date.now()? Does it only do certain kinds of expressions?

```
data-ng-click="$scope.visible = !$scope.visible; $scope.refresh = Date.now()"
```

This isn't a question on how to execute multiple expressions-- it's the issue that only certain expressions will be evaluated.

Comment: why not pass this to a function that does this logic instead of doing it inline?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add many functions in ONE ng-click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813945/how-to-add-many-functions-in-one-ng-click)

Comment: Doing Js functionality in html is not a recommended way

Comment: I chose to inline the logic because it's a piece of example code to be copied and pasted in our code style guide.

It's something I ran into and was unaware that it wouldn't be able to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you cannot use `Date` in an angular expression.

You should either create a function on your scope/controller to handle the click event, or create a function that returns the current time and use that instead of `Date.now()`.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any documentation to show that Date wouldn't work. I'll try this and get back to you!

Comment: [Here's a document that lists the allowed expressions](http://teropa.info/blog/2014/03/23/angularjs-expressions-cheatsheet.html)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to refer **$scope** inside the view. I suggest to do this operation in a function:

```
data-ng-click="onClick()"
```

and inside the controller:

```
$scope.onClick = function(){
    $scope.visible = !$scope.visible; 
    $scope.refresh = Date.now();
}
```

Comment: I chose to inline the logic because it's a piece of example code to be copied and pasted in our code style guide. It's something I ran into and was unaware that it wouldn't be able to be evaluated.

I want to avoid having to add that function to every Controller that uses the code.

Comment: There are smart way to do the same thing in each controller without manually copy/paste it ;)

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I could just make a directive do it.

Comment: I don't think you should watch inside the directive stuff, maybe better controller inheritance but i'm not an expert. google around and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have not to call `$scope` in html binding, you need only the property name:

HTML:

```
data-ng-click="visible = !visible; refresh = Date.now()"
```

JS Controller:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.visible = true;
    $scope.refresh = '';
});
```