# How to call multiple functions on ng-change in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`ng-change = "ControllerName.functionName()"`

here I want to add one more function to that. How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ng-change = "ControllerName.functionName(); ControllerName.otherFunctionName()"`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813945/how-to-add-many-functions-in-one-ng-click

Answer (score 37):

This should do the trick:

```
ng-change = "ControllerName.functionName(); ControllerName.anotherFunction();"
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not rather group the functions in the controller inside another function?

```
function onChangeGroup(){
 doStuff();
 doMoreStuff();
}

<input ng-change="ControllerName.onChangeGroup()"/>
```

Regards

Comment: IMHO, this can obscure what's happening a little bit; it's useful to be able to read through the template and know what sort of actions are triggered by changes on each model. That being said, there is of course a limit; I would *mayyyybe* allow up to three function calls in ngChange without wrapping them in another function, and probably only if they had short, descriptive names. Anything more than three and I'd definitely want to wrap it in a new scope function

Answer (score 7):

This is working properly but one controller in both function.

```
ng-change = "function1();function2();"
```

Answer (score 7):

for angular version 1.* :
   `ng-change = "function1();function2();"`

for angular version 2.* or more:
   `(change)= "function1();function2();"`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add another function in the same double quotes.

```
ng-change = "ControllerName.functionFirst(); ControllerName.functionSecond();"
```

You can use `ng-change` for multi expression by adding semicolon `;` after each expression