# How to add two functions in ng-click=?

Tags: angularjs

i have a button with ng-click= which is opening another html, but i want to have two function on my ng-click= "fisrtFunction(will save the row on which is the button which i'm clicking) secondFunction(will open a new html view). The idea is that i want to ignore one more saving on the new added row. Can you give me some ideas. I'm java dev and angular is not my stren

Regards

Comment: why don't you combine the two functions into a new one in the controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add many functions in ONE ng-click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813945/how-to-add-many-functions-in-one-ng-click)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just execute another function in the body of the other function?

```
$scope.firstFunction = function(){

   $scope.secondFunction();
}

<button ng-click="firstFunction()"> </button>
```

You could also pass the function (secondFunction) in as a parameter and call the parameter like a function.

Alternative would be to separate the functions using `;` so `ng-click="firstFunction(); secondFunction();"` but that will eventually become messy the more you add to it.