# Fetch the user's exact location when he press the start button in IONIC 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I want to know the user's location when they press on a certain button and push it to the database to a certain table with the user id.

How can I do this in IONIC 5?

Comment: Do you mean Ionic 5? It's only out in beta. For support we go by the framework version which is currently Ionic 4. There is a Ionic CLI at v5 but that's not the framework version you should be mentioning when requesting support.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Have you tried ['@ionic-native/geolocation'](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation) and [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation)? You can do something like this:

**1 - Get the current location. We have two variables: latitude and longitude**

```
getCurrentLocation() {    

    let options = {timeout : 10000 , enableHighAccuracy:true};
    let locationObs = new Observable(observable => {
      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options)

      .then(resp => {

        this.latitude =  resp.coords.latitude
        this.longitude = resp.coords.longitude                

        let location = new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude);
        observable.next(location);                


      }).catch( error => {             

        loading.dismiss(); 
        return false;
      })
    })

    return locationObs;
  }
```

**2 - Call the function when the button is clicked. To prevent memory leaks, use unsubscribe after you get the location:**

```
buttonClicked(){   

      let sub = this.getCurrentLocation().subscribe(location => {
           console.log(this.latitude, this.longitude)
           sub.unsubscribe()
      })       
  }
```

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Is there a reason for using an observable in this snippet? If so, then it will need to be unsubscribed as well to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: In my case, I need the exact location of the user, so the observable it's very useful here. 

And yes, the unsubscribe is necessary... I've edited the response.. thank you..

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Now i want my button to do two functions the first is fetching the location and the second is to go the page. i read that you cant do two functions . <ion-button  expand="full" class="ion-padding" color="success" (click)="buttonClicked() openQuestions()">Start</ion-button> .   can you help me what should i do?

Comment: i have tried what you gave me i added the import in the providors page and in the page i want the button which is home import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx'; also in the html <ion-button  expand="full" class="ion-padding" color="success" (click)="buttonClicked()">Start</ion-button> but when i click on the start the following error comes up https://prnt.sc/qfg788

Comment: You are right, it's possible to use two functions on the same button tag. 

Check this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352202/7907226

.About the error, you have to import the observable, like this:

Add this: import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'